# What does the binary code at the beginning of each chapter of The Electric Church signify?

Tags: the-electric-church

At the beginning of each chapter of Jeff Somers' *The Electric Church* there is binary code right below the title of the chapter. This code changes each chapter, but I have noticed some of the codes do repeat.

Are they there just as a bit of extra Sci-Fi fluff to make the book look a bit cooler, or is there a deeper meaning or significance to the codes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It's a hidden message.**

While writing out this question I wrote down each of the binary codes and converted them to decimal, after which I substituted the decimal for the corresponding letter of the alphabet (the binary codes that resulted in a zero I took to be spaces).

| Binary | Decimal | Alphabet |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01001 | 9 | **I** |
| 01110 | 14 | **N** |
| 00000 | 0 |  |
| 10100 | 20 | **T** |
| 01000 | 8 | **H** |
| 00101 | 5 | **E** |

and so on.

The whole message is as follows:

> **IN THE END PRIDE IS ALL NEGATIVE SPACE**

Although it feels like something Avery Cates would say, there doesn't seem to be any significance to the story that I can see.

Comment: 5-bit code? Should have used [Baudot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baudot_code)!